# How to explain Z3's behavior when solving the following Horn clauses?

Tags: z3

I am using Z3 from the unstable branch to experiment with Horn clauses (commit 61385c8489b7fda11b518a67fe308ea3cfe28c3d). I could make Z3 infer a few loop invariants, which was nice. Yet, with the following simple examples I am puzzled by Z3's behavior. What am I missing here?

Example 1:

```
(set-logic HORN)
(declare-const C Int)
(assert (> C 2))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I would expect a model but receive "unknown".

Example 2:

```
(set-logic HORN)
(define-fun step ((I Int) (I1 Int)) Bool (= I1 (+ I 1)))
(define-fun post ((I1 Int)) Bool (= I1 10))
(declare-fun pre (Int) Bool)
(assert (forall ((I Int) (I1 Int)) (=> (and (pre I) (step I I1)) (post I1))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I would expect a model telling me something about pre (e.g., that it is false or that it holds for 9), but receive

```
sat
(model )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am executing your Example 1 with Z3 (both online and local) and I am obtaining

```
WARNING: unknown logic, ignoring set-logic command 
sat 
(model (define-fun C () Int 3) )
```

I am executing your Example 2 with mathsat (local) and I am obtaining

```
sat
( (C 3) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am executing your Example 2 with Z3 (both online and local) and I am obtaining

```
WARNING: unknown logic, ignoring set-logic command 
sat 
(model 
 (define-fun elem!0 () Int 0) 
 (define-fun elem!1 () Int 0) 
 (define-fun pre ((x!1 Int)) Bool false) 
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but please note that my question referes to Z3's PDR engine for solving horn clauses. The (set-logic HORN) part is important. The examples may very well work with other engines - which happens in your case.